# Google Calendar API Event Insertion

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am having problems trying to insert events into a calendar. Here is the code I have so far, taken from the Google API help:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setSummary("Appointment");
event.setLocation("Somewhere");
ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("attendeeEmail"));
event.setAttendees(attendees);
Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));
service.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
```

Except I keep getting

```
        Exception in thread "main"     

    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

"message" : "Invalid Value"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is probably caused by one malformed field. Have you tried omitting some fields to isolate the field that's causing the trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this instead?

```
attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("attendeeEmail@bla.com"));
```

I reproduced the error: it seems google checks emails for an @ sign.
adding @bla.com solved it for me. no more 400 Bad Request